# is there a python equivalent of fromROSMsg/toROSMsg (pcl stack)

Tags: python, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is there a python equivalent of fromROSMsg/toROSMsg (pcl stack)?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9246/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-fromrosmsg/torosmsg-(pcl-stack)/) by [Yianni](https://answers.ros.org/users/215/yianni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2011-02-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no python support in pcl, but you may find this ticket useful [ros-pkg #4440](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4440)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3